# Updating NamedTuple members based on a function and previous value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a `NamedTuple` to represent the state of my game while it's running. The user can alter these settings using key presses, so in my PyGame key handler, I'm writing things like:

```
if key_code == 273:  # Up arrow
    return game_settings._replace(fps=game_settings.fps + 5)
```

Each key press transforms the settings state by using the old value and `_replace`.

I decided to try and emulate [Clojure's `update` function](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) as an exercise, and because it may actually make more code more readable. It takes a function and a key, and updates the value at that key using the function. Example usage:

```
>>> sett = GameSettings(fps=30, is_running=True)

>>> sett.update(lambda x: not x, "is_running")
GameSettings(fps=30, is_running=False)

>>> sett.update2(lambda x: not x, is_running=None)
GameSettings(fps=30, is_running=False)
```

I created two different versions that each behave similarly but are slightly different. Version one accepts a string key. Version two accepts kwargs with a dummy value. I'm not super happy with either though. Having to pass a String to Version one fells messy any error prone. If I typo the String, I'll get an `AttributeError` at runtime. Version two accepting a dummy value also feels off and is also error prone; although I do think it reads nicer without the quotes. The code for each is also quite ugly and dense.

The methods don't actually *need* to accept more than one key (I'll probably never pass more than one at a time), but I figured it barely changes the algorithm and it mirrors `_replace`, so I decided why not.

I'd appreciate any thoughts here on how to set this up better or make the code cleaner.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import NamedTuple, Callable, TypeVar
from functools import reduce

T = TypeVar("T")

class GameSettings(NamedTuple):
    fps: int
    is_running: bool = True

    def update(self, f: Callable[[T], T], *keys) -> GameSettings:
        return reduce(lambda acc, k: acc._replace(**{k: f(getattr(acc, k))}), keys, self)

    def update2(self, f: Callable[[T], T], **kwargs) -> GameSettings:
        return self._replace(**{k: f(getattr(self, k)) for k, _ in kwargs.items()})
```

Comment: I'm skeptical that any of this (using an immutable `NamedTuple` and a `lambda`) is a good idea at all. I wish you had shown the rest of the key handler function.

Comment: @200_success I used an immutable tuple here just because I like representing things as transformations of an immutable state. I come from a mostly FP background, so that's the thought process that I'm used to. Ya, I could have used a dataclass here and it would have been much simpler. The rest of the key handler is just dispatching onto the keys (more of what I posted at the top).

Answer (score 1):

I decided that since I'll likely never need to associate the same function with multiple keys, I might as well just associate the keys with a function directly:

```
def update3(self, **kwargs: Callable[[T], T]) -> GameSettings:
    return self._replace(**{k: f(getattr(self, k)) for k, f in kwargs.items()})

>>> sett = GameSettings(fps=30, is_running=True)

>>> sett.update3(is_running=lambda x: not x)
GameSettings(fps=30, is_running=False)
```

The code still isn't beautiful, but it makes a lot more sense when calling now.